# How to use code to open android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission

Tags: java, android

In my app, I need to use `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. Now I know to go to setting to open it. But some of the application is automatically opened. I want to know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, you want to ask the user for some permissions on app launch. There's a great library to help you do that in Android :

[Github link for the Permission dispatcher library](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher)

You can also check these libraries :

[App-Runtime-Permissions-Android](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/App-Runtime-Permissions-Android)

[Assent](https://github.com/afollestad/assent)

[MarshmallowPermissionManager](https://github.com/RurioLuca/MarshmallowPermissionManager)

Answer (score 0):

Every app that requests the **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** permission and that is installed through the Play Store (version 6.0.5 or higher is required), will have granted the permission automatically.

If instead the app is sideloaded, the permission is not automatically granted. You can try to download and install the Evernote APK from apkmirror.com. As you can see you need to manually grant the permission in **Settings -> Apps -> Draw over other apps**.

It is a new behaviour introduced in Marshmallow 6.0.1.

If you want the app to be sideloaded, you show manually show a prompt and direct the user to enable Draw over other apps permissions from the settings. Have a look at [Requesting permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)